# Having an ERROR while running docker-compose, it doesnt wait for my database to be ready

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a flask application with a Mysql database with docker-compose. However I tried using a lot of techniques to make my docker-compose wait for the database to be ready before firing my flask application. This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  waitfordb:
        image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
        depends_on:
            mysql:
              condition: service_completed_successfully
        environment:
            MYSQL_PORT: "5432"
        networks:
            - backend
        command: mysql:5432
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "12345678"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: flaskmysql
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
      waitfordb:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12345678"
      MYSQL_DB: flaskmysql
  
networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

and in my flask application I've got:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= f"mysql+pymysql://{config.MYSQL_USER}:{config.MYSQL_PASS}@5432/flaskmysql"
```

I'm trying to run:

```
docker-compose --env-file .env up
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '5432' (timed out)")
```

Comment: Is your MySQL database really running on port 5432? 3306 is the usual port for MySQL, whereas 5432 is the usual port for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Tried "3306" just in case. But got the same error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '3306' (timed out)")

Comment: Are you missing a reference to `config.MYSQL_HOST` in that database URI setting?

Comment: I think, @DavidMaze is right. Shouldn't the URI be `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= f"mysql+pymysql://{config.MYSQL_USER}:{config.MYSQL_PASS}@{config.MYSQL_HOST}:5432/flaskmysql"`?

Comment: @DavidMaze , 'If I add the host to be "MySQL" for example like this: f"mysql+pymysql://{config.MYSQL_USER}:{config.MYSQL_PASS}@mysql:5432/flaskmysql"
Im getting this error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")

Comment: The `mysql` container is on the `backend` network but the `web` container isn't.  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file, so all of the containers are on the Compose-managed `default` network.

Answer (score 0):

Specify "mysql" (container's name) as a host.

final uri is : "mysql+pymysql://USER:PASS@mysql:5432/flaskmysql"

Comment: I added the mysql host name and got this error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")